Resolving Compatibility Issue: Integrating MyBatis with Spring Boot 3.3.0-Snapshot and Java 17
Encountering a compatibility hurdle while integrating MyBatis with Spring Boot 3.3.0-Snapshot. My attempt to include the MyBatis dependency resulted in a requirement stating it needs Spring Boot version greater than or equal to 3.0.0 and 3.3.0 M1. Given my intention to leverage the latest Spring Boot version, potentially coupled with Java 17, how can I reconcile this discrepancy to successfully integrate MyBatis into my project?

For integrating MyBatis with Spring Boot 3.3.0-Snapshot and Java 17.

Unless you want to try some specific feature/fix of 3.3.0, you should use the latest released version which is Spring Boot 3.2.5. Snapshots are mainly for developers (of Spring or MyBatis).
